# how to set a default faultcontract attribute in wcf-service

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

is there a way to set a "default"-faultcontract e.g. for all methods in a wcf-service-class?
like

```
[ServiceContract]
[DefaultFaultContract(typof(MyServiceFault))]
class MyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
}
```

instead of:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICustomerService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFault))]
    void DoWork();
}
```

I appreciate a link for a "Step-By-Step" Guide.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the "right" way to do this, but I just posted an answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441294/remoting-in-c-vs-versioning/7441994#7441994)

[This code might be usefull to you](http://icareo.free.fr/ups/1330884938.cs)

It builds a proxy which catches every exception that occured when calling members of an object implementing a specific interface.
You could use this on wpf channels.

```
IMyInterface myService = [...];
IMyInterface myExceptionLoggedService = ExceptionProxyGenerator.Generate<IMyInterface>(myService);
(myExceptionLoggedService  as IExceptionProxy).Error+=(sender,method,exception)=>{
   // do what you want on exception
};
// Use my service :
myExceptionLoggedService.MyOkFunction();// ok
myExceptionLoggedService.MyExceptionFunction();// calling the above delegate
```

You could rewrite a bit this class to have the kind of behavior you want (like not rethrowing the exception on error and returning null -if function is not returning void-)